# Why Leftmost Prefix Matching Occurred In This SQL

Tags: mysql

MySQL version is 8.0.33.

Given a table `student`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `student`
(
    `id`     int(11)                            NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `stu_no` varchar(12)                        NOT NULL,
    `age`    int(11)                            NOT NULL,
    `name`   varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_stu_no` (`stu_no`),
    KEY `idx_stu_name` (`name`),
    KEY `idx_stu_no_age` (`stu_no`, `age`) USING BTREE,
    KEY `idx_stu_no_age_name` (`stu_no`, `age`, `name`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Here is a SQL query:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM student where name = (123) and age = (234);
```

The `EXPLAIN` result told me that this query will use index `idx_stu_no_age_name`

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+----------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys                    | key                 | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+----------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | student | NULL       | index | idx_stu_name,idx_stu_no_age_name | idx_stu_no_age_name | 1065    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+----------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

According to leftmost prefix matching rule, this query should not use any index
because there is no any union index with column(name, age).

ADDITION INFORMATION:

If add a new colume to table `student`

```sql
alter table student add column_name2 int;
```

index will work as expected:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | student | NULL       | ALL  | idx_stu_name  | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Put another way, the index doesn't need to be exclusively name, age.  It just has to have both name and age to be useful in that query.  I expect that second explain isn't from the same query as adding another column to the table shouldn't change that behavior unless the column is referenced in the query

Comment: ahh good point Martin

Answer (score 1):

I haven't spent much time looking at MySQL explain plans but this all seems clear if you use [`EXPLAIN FORMAT=TREE`](https://dbfiddle.uk/j-7SQj_D).

This shows

```
-> Filter: ((student.age = 234) and (student.`name` = 123))  (cost=0.35 rows=1)
    -> Index scan on student using idx_stu_no_age_name  (cost=0.35 rows=1)
```

for your first case - So the index is just used as something to scan because it contains all the columns. It is not able to actually perform an index seek against it as there is no predicate on `stu_no` as you point out.

and

```
-> Filter: ((student.age = 234) and (student.`name` = 123))  (cost=0.35 rows=1)
    -> Table scan on student  (cost=0.35 rows=1)
```

for your second case.

The index no longer "[covers the query](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index)" as you have `SELECT *` and the index does not contain `column_name2` so a table scan is used instead of that index.

Presumably potentially it *could* have done a seek on `idx_stu_name` on the name part and then lookups back to the base table to get the missing column values hence listing that as a `possible_keys` - but it didn't do that.

Comment: And as for how the original query is able to return `id` without that being included in the index explicitly I assume it is included implicitly as a row locator back to the base table

Comment: As shown by `SHOW EXTENDED INDEX FROM \`student\`;`